# Parport scanners

Tags: canon, scanner, sane, xsane

I have an old Canon N640 P ex scanner, that uses parport to connect. I have installed Sane and XSane.
I have also enabled canon_pp, after that I have also run `sane-find-scanner`, but it says:

```
  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

I have tried to search also with XSane, but it also detects no scanners.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following possible answer [Here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/simple-scan/+question/184353)

```
Working fine (installing, scanner and parallel port access)

open Terminal

1)
sudo apt-get install libsane libsane-extras libsane-extras sane sane-utils xsane xsane-common libieee1284-3

2)
sudo gedit / etc / sane.d / dll.conf '

In this file, we look for our scanner line (in this case canon_pp) and uncomment (remove the # sign in front).
Save and close the file.

3)
sudo gedit / etc / sane.d / canon_pp.conf '

In this file, uncomment the line force_nibble and the line FB630P (11001100 style .. Also works for FB330P, N340P, N640P). Save and close the file

4)

    close terminal

5)
Unplugged the scanner, plug it again ... launch Applications / Graphics / XSane Image Scanner ... and our scanner should be detected ...
```

Comment: Good Luck! I have an OLD laptop in a closet with a par port, and I haven't even seen that in like a year. I know you just want to get it working, but places like thrift shops often have them for like $3-4 (assuming you're in the US) Just be sure to check online for drivers before purchase.